# What is the distinction between alkyloxy and alkoxy prefixes, if any?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

The IUPAC nomenclature guidelines reference alkyloxy and alkoxy prefixes at different points. Is there any distinction, at the level of a principle or rationale, between the use cases for the two? For example, is there an underlying reason why cyclopentyloxybenzene is or isn't preferable to cyclopentoxybenzene?

Comment: I have ever seen only methoxy-, not methyloxy-. The latter may be formally more correct and consistent, the former get used as a rational abbreviation for some short alkyloxy groups. It may differ between alkyls due historical reasons. I guess octyloxy may be preferred to octoxy.